# Is it possible to write results of a find query to a collection from termianl?

Tags: mongodb

This is my query.

```
db.final.find( { 'skills.skillList.skill.name' : { $exists : true } } )
```

I want to write results of this query to a separate collection.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch results to the client and insert into another collection. It's not possible in the database, without retrieving results.